# Is TransactionScope still running after server failover and how does the database roll back the changes automatically when the server failover?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Here is my code

```cs
 using (var context = DbContextCreator.Create())
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { Timeout = TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout }; // 60 seconds. 

        using (var dbContextTransaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM SRE.ActionHistory WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)");

                bool isDuplicated = context.ActionHistory
                    .Any(x => x.StatusId == (int)eActionHistoryStatus.Pending &&
                                x.ActionId == (int)Action &&
                                x.DateTime >= timeToCheck &&
                                x.CustomerId == Customer.Id);
                if (!isDuplicated)
                {
                    context.ActionHistory.Add(actionHistory);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    dbContextTransaction.Complete();
                    return actionHistory;
                }
                throw new BizException(BizErrorCodes.NotAllowedToDoAction);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // It will roll back automatically if the Complete() method isn't invoked or the timeout takes longer than the specified timeout.
                throw;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have two servers one for .NET code and the other for the database.

The server that I expect to failover is the server that holds the .NET code.

Actually, I need to release the lock even if the server fails.

To make my code clean, which one I should use Transaction Scope or BeginTransaction?

Comment: I would expect SQL Server will rollback the transaction when the SQL client connection is terminated due to the failover.

Comment: `TransactionScope` is cleaner in terms of usage (because of automatic enlistment) but `BeginTransaction` is probably more efficient. `catch (Exception ex) { throw; }` is a waste of time, you may as well not catch. `TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK` is a bad idea, as it's putting a complete block on the table. Better to do `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` in a `FromSqlRaw` and read just the rows you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server will rollback the transaction when the SQL client connection is terminated due to the failover.